Open Source and offline software for image upscaling
I'm looking for a open source, and self-hosted/offline software to do image upscaling locally on my computer.
Here are my requirements:

It needs to be compatible Windows.
Have a user-friendly UI.
Open source and i need to be able to run it locally.


Excluding the point for opensource where is one product which I use and can recommend:
xnview
You can upscale images with very good control how, how much, etc. And this can be done in batch. Here is one example screen of the process:


I've been using for a while and recommend Upscayl  It checks off pretty much all of your requirements, you can run it locally and it is open source the UI is very friendly and pretty straight-foward. You can also choose what model you want to use to upscale the image.

